# PHP MySQL statment with AND and OR

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a PHP MySQL statement and basically what I want is to check for that table element matches and then check a second table element matches or a third table element matches, sort of like this

`if ref=ref (AND page=page OR allpages=1)`

that means search for all pages with `ref=ref` and then in that recordset check if `page=page` or if all `pages=1`

so MySQL statement is this:

```
 $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM content WHERE ref='$ref' AND page_ref='$page_ref' OR allPages='1');
```

But it is taking records from the db that don’t match the ref but `allpages=1`

Is there some way of bracketing this or restructuring the statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if ref=ref (AND page=page OR allpages=1)` was nearly right, but you want the `AND` out of the brackets:

```
if ref=ref AND (page=page OR allpages=1)
```

Implemented:

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM content WHERE ref='$ref' AND (page_ref='$page_ref' OR allPages='1')");
```

Note: you were missing a closing `"` from  the query as well (though I suspect this was a copy error when creating the question)

Further improvement (concatenation and backticks):

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `content` WHERE `ref`='".$ref."' AND (`page_ref`='".$page_ref."' OR `allPages`=1)");
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add brackets like this:

```
SELECT * FROM content 
 WHERE ref='ref' 
   AND (page_ref='page_ref' OR allPages='1')
-------^------------------------------------^----Add here
```

So your whole query should be:

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM content WHERE ref='$ref' AND (page_ref='$page_ref' OR allPages='1')");
```

Comment: Please, do not use `mysql_*` in samples since they're deprecated

Answer (score 1):

User `Operator Precedance`.

> > The precedence of an operator specifies how "tightly" it binds two expressions together. For example, in the expression 1 + 5 * 3, the answer is 16 and not 18 because the multiplication ("*") operator has a higher precedence than the addition ("+") operator. Parentheses may be used to force precedence, if necessary. For instance: (1 + 5) * 3 evaluates to 18.

```
"SELECT * FROM content WHERE ref='".$ref."' AND (page_ref='".$page_ref."' OR allPages=1")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
SELECT * FROM content WHERE ref='$ref' AND (page_ref='$page_ref' OR allPages='1')
```

it is a priority matter. You can read about operators precedence in the corresponding [manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html).

Also, remember, that `mysql_*` functions are officially deprecated, so use `mysqli_` or `PDO` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can add brackets to your mySQL statement in just the same way as you add them to a PHP statement.  Just make sure your expression is bracketed in the same way as your desired logic.

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM content WHERE ref='$ref' AND (page_ref='$page_ref' OR allPages='1')");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set braces around the OR comparison:

```
 WHERE ref='$ref' AND ( page_ref='$page_ref' OR allPages='1' )
```